# Can I install Laravel 5 on GoDaddy shared linux hosting?

Tags: godaddy, laravel

My problem is that I don't know whether a GoDaddy shared server provides the following extensions which are required for Laravel 5.0?

- PHP >= 5.4 with all common Extension and also
- Mcrypt PHP Extension
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extention

and for  my project purpose

- Fileinfo PHP Extension and
- GD PHP Extention

Answer (score 1):

The odds are they support those modules as they are pretty basic and standard one's. But to be sure you can make use of a simple PHP function to confirm they are indeed enabled.

Create a PHP script and make its contents the following:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This will tell you all about the PHP modules (and more) that are enabled as well as what version of PHP you are using.